# Outlook Web Add-in using Angular 5 random error "Office.js has not fully loaded" on second time when Add-in opened

Tags: angular, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on Outlook Web Addin trying get it work using Angular 5, I have followed the official documentation provided by microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-angular

yes the above link is for excel but the basic setup i can find its similar.
I have initialized the Office in main.ts like

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}


try{
Office.initialize = function () {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};
}catch(err){

}
```

i am using routes in this addin which is declared and setup in app.module.ts the code is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ArchiveComponent } from './archive/archive.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ArchiveComponent,
    SearchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path:'archive',
        component:ArchiveComponent

      },
      {
        path:'search_archive',
        component:SearchComponent
      }
    ])

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  ],


  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have tested the routes /#archive in local it works and displays the html inside the ArchiveComponent template page. only when the bootstrap is not done in Office.initailize.

When i hosted the addin on my apache server and installed it in my outlook web it works for only first time. ArchiveComponent component code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const Office: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-archive',
  templateUrl: './archive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./archive.component.css']
})
export class ArchiveComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId)


  }

}
```

Console inside the oninit method prints in browser from Outlook web when opened first time, after that when i reopen the addin next time on same Outlook web it throws the error

```
Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
```

below is the image from console having 2 errors and 1st one is unknown but its from addin routes and 2nd one is Print 1st time

[image]

Same addin which is build by default angular version works great but facing problem when trying to migrate this to Angular 5.

I can guess that there is some thing which i am missing at the Office.initialize but not sure.

Reason to migrate is to use route inside the add-in so that for 2 different addins i don have create 2 projects.

Comment: While debugging the add-in, can you check that the "Office.initialize = ..." statement is called each time the add-in loads? The office.js javascript error indicates that it's undefined.

Comment: After doing some practices, I found that there is some error also throwing in pollyfill.js when i open the same thing Internet Explorer. I have uncommented some lines in pollyfill.ts to add supports for the browser and every thing worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: For the good tests and getting better error explaination its always good for Microsoft Office Add-Ins to test with Internet explorer.I found the better error discription in Internet explorer instead in Fire Fox for above problem.

After doing some practices, I found that there is some error also throwing in pollyfill.js when i open the same thing Internet Explorer. I have uncommented some lines in pollyfill.ts to add supports for the browser and every thing worked fine.

Just uncomment these lines in pollyfill.ts

```
   /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```